# What are these toilet washers/retainers for?

Tags: toilet

Installing a new toilet, it came with these plastic washers, but I've never seen them with any other toilets I've installed, and I'm not really sure what they're for.

[image: toilet bolts]

The center is slightly conical and is raised by about 1/4". They came in the bag with the other metal parts, and the white plastic covers came in a separate bag.

What are they, and where are they supposed to go?

Comment: Do they fit snugly inside that dome-shaped toilet bowl installation cap? It looks like something I would push down over the bolt that sticks up after installation to provide a place that the caps can seat onto. It's a neat idea, if that's what it is. My cats like to unseat those caps and kick them around on the bathroom floor.

Comment: The white washers are for the caps (and perfectly clip into a groove at the bottom). The ones in question fit almost halfway into the caps, but don't attach in any way and just wobble around inside.

Comment: They are the spacers that go below the flat white (bottom of the dome screw covers) not all kits have them some are more solid and spread the load better than just the plastic.

Comment: @EdBeal on top of the toilet? Can't be - without then the caps are perfectly flush, so with them the caps would sit way too high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not to hold the white cap in place as Robert suggested, I would say they are used to hold the bolts upright while placing the toilet. There would need to be a void under the toliet of course.

Comment: That is precisely what they are for. To hold the bolts upright.